# Upgrading Symfony from 3 to 4 getting error: "no registered migrations"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony3.x

Trying to upgrade a project from Symfony 3.x to 4.4 and running into some issues with the doctrine migrations.

Currently when trying to run migrations I am receiving this error:

> [ERROR] The version "latest" couldn't be reached, there are no registered
> migrations.

When running the following command to print out my doctrine config:

```
php app/console config:dump-reference doctrine_migrations
```

It basically gives me the default doctrine migrations config information.

Currently the project does not use **Symfony Flex** as I'm suspecting that makes a difference on where this config lives within the project. Doctrine config I have inside my `config/config.yml` file.

```
doctrine_migrations:
    # A list of namespace/path pairs where to look for migrations.
    migrations_paths:
        # Prototype
        'DoctrineMigrations': '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Migrations'

    # Storage to use for migration status metadata.
    storage:
        # The default metadata storage, implemented as a table in the database.
        table_storage:
            table_name: 'migrations'
            version_column_name:  'version'
```

Running the doctrine migrate command returns

```
+------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Configuration                                                                                              |
+------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Storage    | Type                 | Doctrine\Migrations\Metadata\Storage\TableMetadataStorageConfiguration |
|            | Table Name           | doctrine_migration_versions                                            |
|            | Column Name          | version                                                                |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Database   | Driver               | Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\PgSQL\Driver                                  |
|            | Name                 | api                                                                    |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Versions   | Previous             | 0                                                                      |
|            | Current              | 0                                                                      |
|            | Next                 | Already at latest version                                              |
|            | Latest               | 0                                                                      |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Migrations | Executed             | 0                                                                      |
|            | Executed Unavailable | 0                                                                      |
|            | Available            | 0                                                                      |
|            | New                  | 0                                                                      |
+------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see the table name etc does not match up with what's inside the config. I believe I'm missing something here to get the migrations to run but can't seem to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

There is no `config/config.yml` file in symfony4 by default. It seems that this file is ignored.

Move your `doctrine_migrations:` section from  `config/config.yml` to `config/packages/doctrine_migrations.yaml` file

[image: example]

Comment: See I read that it should be in a `doctrine_migrations.yml` file on the Symfony website but when I did move the file there with the correct contents it still wasn't been picked up. Maybe because I haven't moved everything out the `config.yml` into there separate files possibly?

Comment: Maybe. You can debug by `php app/console debug:config DoctrineMigrationsBundle` command.  When I run `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:status` I get a table, where the last row is `Migration Namespaces | App\Migrations       | /app/src/Migrations`, but in your case, there is no this row. https://i.imgur.com/L8PEmBI.png